# Rails "Browser Gem" support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new to Rails, I'm trying to get the "browser" gem working.
 (https://github.com/fnando/browser)

I was hoping someone had some example code they code post.  I installed the gem by putting `gem "browser", require: "browser/browser"` in my gemfile.

I ran `gem install browser`

So I don't really know how to use the gem to actually get the users browser info.  I tried just doing this as a test in the view `<%= browser.full_version %>` but I get `Template::Error (undefined local variable or method browser'`

any example code on what to put in a view/modal/controller would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate the object. So you can do something like this:

```
def index
  @browser = Browser.new(request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])
end
```

Then you can call the object in your view:

```
Device: <%= @browser.device.name %><br>
Platform: <%= @browser.platform.name %><br>
Info: <%= @browser.to_s %><br>
```

PS. I tried using this gem but found [useragent](https://github.com/gshutler/useragent) which seemed to better display the information I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install the gem and "call it" in your view.

For example:

```
<% if browser.device.mobile? || browser.platform.android? %>
```

Comment: Please explain it in more detail as the original poster seems to have severe troubles.

Answer (score -1):

To install this gem you need:

- add gem declaration to Gemfile
- run `bundle install` from the console
- restart your development server

P.S. when you are starting to use any gem, you should carefully read gem's README first. In 95% cases they are documented good enough.

Comment: Thanks.  I have the gem installed.  I'm trying to figure out how to use it though.  the documentation says to just do 

 require "browser" 
 browser = Browser.new("Some User Agent", accept_language: "en-us")

Comment: I added   require "browser" to my model.  I'm new to using GEMs so trying to figure out how to actually use this browser gem.